# Docker Container port issue: Not able to access tomcat url using host ip

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-container

I am new to Docker, I have setup Docker Container on an **Amazon Linux box**.
I have a docker file which installs **tomcat java** and a war.
I can see all the installations present in the docker container when I navigate through the container in the exact folders I have mentioned in the Docker file.
When I run the Docker container it says **tomcat server** has started and I have also tailed the logs so I can see the service is running.

But when I open the host IP URL and **8080 port** it says URL can't be reached.

These are the commands to build and run the file which works fine and I can see the status as running.

```
docker build -t friendly1 .             
docker run  -p 8080:8080 friendly1
```

What am I missing here? Request some help on this.

```
 FROM centos:latest
 RUN yum -y update && \
 yum -y install wget && \
 yum -y install tar && \
 yum -y install zip unzip


ENV JAVA_HOME /opt/java/jdk1.7.0_67/
ENV CATALINA_HOME /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.70
ENV SAVIYNT_HOME /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.70/webapps
ENV PATH $PATH:$JAVA_HOME/jre/jdk1.7.0_67/bin:$CATALINA_HOME/bin:$CATALINA_HOME/scripts:$CATALINA_HOME/apache-tomcat-7.0.70/bin

ENV JAVA_VERSION 7u67
ENV JAVA_BUILD 7u67


RUN mkdir /opt/java/
RUN wget https://<S3location>/jdk-7u67-linux-x64.gz && \
 tar -xvf jdk-7u67-linux-x64.gz && \
 #rm jdk*.gz && \
 mv jdk* /opt/java/


# Install Tomcat
ENV TOMCAT_MAJOR 7
ENV TOMCAT_VERSION 7.0.70

RUN mkdir /opt/tomcat/
RUN wget https://<s3location>/apache-tomcat-7.0.70.tar.gz  && \
 tar -xvf apache-tomcat-${TOMCAT_VERSION}.tar.gz && \
 #rm apache-tomcat*.tar.gz && \
 mv apache-tomcat* /opt/tomcat/

RUN chmod +x ${CATALINA_HOME}/bin/*sh

WORKDIR /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.70/

CMD "startup.sh"  && tail -f /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.70/logs/*
EXPOSE 8080
```

Comment: from the place where you run `docker`, doest `curl localhost:8080` not work either?

Comment: Could you add the Dockerfile? Did you `EXPOSE` the port 8080?

Comment: Yes I have exposed port 8080

Comment: curl localhost:8080 -------from host 
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
curl localhost:8080--------- from container
curl: (7) Failed connect to localhost:8080; Connection refused

Comment: Have updated the docker file used

Comment: Shouldn't the `EXPOSE` be before `CMD` seeing as `CMD` is the command to start the container? Try that.

Comment: The `EXPOSE` command only serves as documentation and doesnt actually publish the port. See [docker reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose)

Comment: What does docker logs <container_id> gives you ?

Comment: If you are getting error inside container that means your tomcat server is not running well.